# Problems with encoding ASP.NET Core & SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have problems with russian language in my database. I read data from xlsx file. For reading I use library OfficeOpenXml. While debugging there is no problems with encoding, but after adding to database there are only `???`. 
And here is what I've got:

[image: only "???"]

Comment: If its colation you can check that on your SQL side by running this query then you need to update it if it is not what you need:  SELECT collation_name FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name = 'database name';  Here is more info:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Brad nothing changed

Comment: Are your character columns set to unicode (ex: `nvarchar(max)`)?

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Your code is wide open to sql injection. You should NEVER EVER EVER build up a string like this and execute it. My friend bobby tables love this kind of code. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing database collation on Cyrillic_General_CI_AS

Answer (score 1):

ensure your datatypes on the string fields are the "n" versions for strings.  nChar, nvarchar, nText so that you will not loose data when dealing with nonANSI charsets

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017